# How to match pattern using Regex and avoid concurrent characters and symbols

Tags: android, regex

I need to validate the password.

The conditions are as follows:

- password must be 8 characters long
- include a number
- an uppercase character
- a lowercase character
- it should not accept concurrent characters like 888,ccc etc.
- double repetition is allowed but not thrice.

Special characters are optional.
I am attempting to use this Regex :

> ```
> > final String PASSWORD_PATTERN =
> > "^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?:([\\w\\d*?!:;])\\1?(?!\\1))+$";
> ```

This regex not matching my above needs

Comment: Using Regex is not best scenario here. I am assuming that you do not care about security, Write this as a functions, because in one month you will have no idea what is regex stands for.

Comment: That doesn't answered my question. So what should I do according to you If I consider security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that there is an uppercase char as well as a lowercase char, you might use 2 times a positive lookahead.

If you would allow double repetition but not 3 times, you could use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not what you capture in the charcter class followed by 2 times a backreference to what is captured:

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*([\w\d*?!:;])\1\1)[\w\d*?!:;]+$
```

In Java:

```
final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*([\\w\\d*?!:;])\\1\\1)[\\w\\d*?!:;]+$";
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=.{8,20}$)` Assert a digit
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Assert a lowercase char
- `(?=.*[0-9])` Assert a digit
- `(?!.*([\w\d*?!:;])\1\1)` Assert no 3 times repetition
- `[\w\d*?!:;]+` Match what is listed in the character class 1+ times
- `$` Assert end of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBkDhS/1)

Note that if you use `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` the negatied character class would also match newlines.